# Gnome: Is there any way to hide/disable the location icon in the top bar?

Tags: gnome

I just upgraded my Ubuntu-Gnome.  With the upgrade a new icon appeared in the system menu of the top bar and a new item appeared in the menu regarding the location services.

[image]

I have location services turn off in the privacy settings page so I have no use for this indicator and would like to prevent it from cluttering up my desktop.

I don't care if the item in the drop down menu is still there or not, I just want the icon gone.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing since the Location Icon appeared, but I'm not happy with removing the entire panel of icons.

I created a tiny extension to hide the Location Icon whenever the Location Services are disabled: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1274/location-icon-autohide/

Comment: Absolutely awesome,  Thank You for your work.  (on a side note, this should not require an extension, it should be default, but that doesn't take away from your great work)

Comment: Luckily they removed it from 3.26 completely: location icon is no longer present in tray drop down.

Comment: Yea!! Must have been enough people annoyed about it.....

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is only way for now to hide all aggregateMenu icons: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/

Comment: unfortunately, this only works if I want to remove the whole menu panel.  as I use several extensions that use that menu, this does not work, it will just have to ignore the icon. Not the answer I was hoping for but, NO is an answer as well.

Comment: yes, that's why a wrote about hiding ALL the thing.
at least it's known that this location icon is a part of aggregateMenu.